# How do I correct my code so that it finds the exceptions and quits accordingly and if its valid it tries the string mutation?

Tags: python, exception

Here is my code:

```
string = input("Enter a sting")    
pos = int(input("Enter the position to be modified"))

try:        
    b = string.split()        
    b[pos] = 'k'        
    b = "".join(b)
    print(b)

except:
    if string == "":
        print("Enter a valid string")
        quit()

    if pos not in range(len(string)):
        print("Enter a valid position to be modified")
        quit()
```

Comment: Provide an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you try out the code with either a wrong index or an empty string, you will see that the program will run with an IndexError. You can catch that in your except clause. Judging by your question, you said you wanted to quit the program when the exception is caught so the below code will work. I modified the error message in order to not confuse the user as to what they should do next.

```
string = input("Enter a sting: ")
pos = int(input("Enter the position to be modified: "))

try:
    b = string.split()
    b[pos] = 'k'
    b = "".join(b)
    print(b)

except IndexError as e:
    if string == "":
        print("Error: Need to enter a valid string.")

    if pos not in range(len(string)):
        print("Error: Need to enter a valid position to be modified.")
```